# Getting parse exception [match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query] in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

not able to get the results with the below syntax in the current version.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "cid": {
              "query": [
                "TEST"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the documentation for the [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), you'll see that the `query` parameter takes a string and not an array:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "cid": {
              "query": "TEST"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

PS: You should really spend some time in the documentation to learn how to craft those queries, it would really help you.